# Put value to autocomplete in Orbeon 4.5

Tags: orbeon

It is possible to put some values to autocomplete control in Orbeon?

Let's say that in my form there are two fields: firstname and middle name. Is it possible to put values of these two fields into autocomplete?

Here's a code sample: https://gist.github.com/pablo09/126ee7864125b95b0d75

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete control calls a service you provide that returns the values it shows. Ideally you'd be able to refer to the value of another field by putting in the URL something like `/path/to/your/service?first-name={$first-name}`. However, for now, instead of `$first-name`, your need to use `xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/user-info/first-name`, where `user-info` is the name of the section in which you have your *first name* field.

And note that [RFE 431](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/431) calls for this to be improved, so you can refer to other fields' values more easily.

Comment: Sorry, I have a little problem with that - I set resource URL just like you said, but it's not working, my autocomplete is still empty. Could you edit my code sample and give me a minimal example how this should be done?

Comment: If you want the autocomplete to depend on `control-3`, with your form you'd write something like: `/path/to/your/service?value={xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/control-3}`. But I'd recommend you rename the section and the controls, so you have names that are more telling. I hope this helps!

Comment: I guess it's a little misunderstanding. I know how to put values to autocomplete control from my service (using REST webservice), but I'm asking if there a chance to avoid using service: I need to put into autocomplete some values which are already in my form (in some fields). As I mentioned, there are two fields: first-name na middlename and I want to rewrite those values into autocomplete.

Comment: To give you more details: when my form gets loaded, using parameters in URL I'm setting some fields (read-only output text): ID1, ID2, ID3. Then, user has to select one out of those 3 ID's. Of course, I can create a service and normally using autocomplete put those iD into it. But I want to avoid downloading the same data twice. Maybe I could write some <xf:action> to achieve this?

Comment: The autocomplete allows you to have data be in an instance (instead of coming from a service). This is called the "static" mode, and you can read more about it on https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-XBL-Components-~-Autocomplete. However, this mode isn't exposed by the Form Builder UI, so to use it you need to edit the source of the form. Is this something that could work for you?

Comment: Thanks - it'll give it a try.